# Why can't the iostream be found in Xcode 5?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

When I updated from Xcode 4.6 to xcode5 , I started getting an error about iostream file not found.

None of my attempts to fix this have worked.

Comment: I don't see a c++ tag, which I would have thought relevant.  Unless one of us is way off track.

Comment: I don't think you have iostream in iOS. Are you working on a C++ project?

Comment: @Plague Yes you do.  Plus the OP needs to make the tag edit so we can be sure he knows what he's talking about (he mentions ios5 when I think he means Xcode 5, so it looks like he doesn't pay much attention to detail).

Comment: @trojanfoe Yeah I guess he meant Xcode 5. Thanks for pointing that out, I guess I came out wrong. To run C++ files on the an iOS project, you have to set the compiler flags right? I don't know whether he is running a pure C++ project or an iOS project. Lets wait and see

Comment: I am running ios project on xcode 5 and ios 7 sdk

Comment: It'd be helpful to explain what you've tried so that people don't waste their time suggesting things that you've already done.

Comment: I find solution,suppose have whole project as Objective C++ (in this case, by changing .m to .mm), which means C++ can be used throughout.hope if someone else have similar issue this answer help

Comment: @tinglan Post that as an answer an then accept it. That'll remove this question from the unanswered list, so people don't spend more time trying to help after you've solved the problem.